# CKeditor in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I installed Ckeditor following the instruction in [this repository](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)

I created a simple rails application adding

`gem 'ckeditor'`

to the Gemfile and then running `bundle install` from command line.

I created a scaffold with only one text field. I wanted to have a cktext_area rather than a normal text_area in the create/update action.

However, I get this error

`undefined method 'cktext_area' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb66fe5a8>`

if I substitute the form text area with this

`<%= javascript_include_tag :ckeditor %>
<%= f.cktext_area :name%>`

I ran the installation as written in github, it seems it isn't able to find the appropriate helper. Even if I try to insert `cktext_area_tag("test_area", "Ckeditor")` it isn't able to find the correct helper.

I'm using Rails 3.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Hey first I also got this error and then when i restarted the server everything worked fine.
Try it.Hope it gets working.